# Google Maps shows "For development purposes only"

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps show the message "For development purposes only" when I try to show it in my webpage:

[image]

How could I make this message go away?

My code is like that:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {  
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5792659,8.6744471);
    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5792659,8.6744471);
    var div = document.getElementById('map');
  }
</script>
```

Then later I have

```
<p>
  <a
    href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//50.5792659,8.6744471/@50.579266,8.674447,16z"
    target="_blank"
  >Route berechnen</a>
</p>
```

I don't see where this message originates from.

Comment: I know this questions is already answered, but In case you didn't know, there is a tool called Google Maps Platform API Checker for Google Chrome that lets you debug your Google Maps integration -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-platform-api/mlikepnkghhlnkgeejmlkfeheihlehne

Comment: who needs temporarily, there is an extension: 
  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-for-development-pu/iggdebapgficoedcjkfoncfkepipbpce

Comment: What happens if I use this "for dev. purposes only".map for a released final project? has it a usage limit? will I get banned? has someone test it?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Google Maps is no longer free. You have to associate a credit card so that you can get billed if your site has requests that exceed the $200 credit they give you monthly for free. That is why you get the watermarked maps.

For more information, see: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

**Update:** 
A common problem with the new billing system is that you now have to activate each API separately. They all have different pricing (some are even free), so Google makes a point of having you enable them individually for your domain. 
I was never a heavy user of Google Maps, but I get the feeling that there are many more APIs now than there used to be.

So if you're still getting a restricted usage message after you've enabled billing, find out what API you need exactly for the features you want to offer, and check if it's enabled. 
The API settings are annoyingly hard to find.

1. Go to this link:
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard.
2. Then you select your project in the dropdown.
3. Go to library on the left pane.
4. Browse the available APIs and enable the one you need.

Comment: Pricing on map loads `-->` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/usage-and-billing#embed

Comment: thanks a lot, you save my day. And for FYI, for the first time linking your account with google, you will get free 300$.

Comment: Does this take a couple days to go into effect?  I did this a couple days ago, but still receiving the message on my maps.  Even click around and made sure I accepted every agreement.....  I see where the traffic is coming into it on the dashboard

Comment: No, it doesn't usually take long. My experience is minutes. But you may need to enable different APIs for things to work. What error message are you getting, @DigitalMystery?

Comment: It is on my mobile app.  At first its the popup "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."  Click OK and the map shows the above message.  I am using my key as well..... @VictoriaRuiz

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about mobile apps. You should probably open a new question with information about your app, what features of the Maps API you're using, and how you set it all up.

Comment: @DigitalMystery and Ramprasath Selvam, have a look at my update. You probably need to enable more APIs to get things to work again.

Answer (score 56):

Watermarked with ￼“**for development purposes only**” is returned when any of the following is true:

1. The request is missing an API key.
2. Billing has not been enabled on your account.
3. The provided billing method is invalid (for example an expired credit card).
4. A self-imposed daily limit has been exceeded.

Answer (score 33):

As Victoria wrote, Google Maps is no longer free, but you can switch your map provider. You may be interested in OpenStreetMap, there is an easy way to use it on your site described here: https://handyman.dulare.com/switching-from-google-maps-to-openstreetmap/

Unfortunately, on the OpenStreetMap, there is no easy way to provide directions from one point to another, there is also no street view.

Comment: How to do this using Angular 6?

Comment: i added the open street map from that link to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLj1uaqc/

Answer (score 10):

As recommended in a comment, I used the "[Google Maps Platform API Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-platform-api/mlikepnkghhlnkgeejmlkfeheihlehne)" Chrome add-in to identify and resolve the issue.

Essentially, this add-in directed me to [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) where I was able to sign in to Google and create a free API key.

Afterwards, I updated my JavaScript and it immediately resolved this issue.

Old JavaScript: ...script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" ...

Updated Javascript:...script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****GOOGLE API KEY******&v=3" ...

The add-in then validated the JS API call. Hope this helps someone resolve the issue quickly!

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For my purposes I ended up using an alternative https://www.openstreetmap.org/ .

Answer (score 6):

Now google maps is free for development only.

> If you want to use map free like earlier, then create an account with
>   valid details (billing, payment, etc.) google gives $200 MONTHLY CREDIT
>   Which is EQUIVALENT To FREE USAGE
>
> For more details please see Googles new price details: [google map new
>   pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)

Also see the old price details: [Old one](https://developers.google.com/maps/previous-pricing)

Comment: Hi , can you let me know , In how many visits the 200$ free credit might get exhausted , any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

try this code it doesn't show “For development purposes only”

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.3076008,51.4803216&z=16&output=embed" height="450" width="600"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

## If your [mapTypeId](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/google_maps/google_maps_types.htm) is `SATELLITE` or `HYBRID`

well, it is just a watermark, you can hide it if you change the `<div>` that has `z-index=100`
I use

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("*").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("zIndex") == 100) {
            $(this).css("zIndex", "-100");
        }
    })}
, 10);
```

or you can use

```
map.addListener('idle', function(e) {
    //same function
}
```

but it is not as responsive as `setInterval`

Comment: what do you mean by "responsive" ?

Comment: faster, but not more efficient

Comment: If these methods worked once, they do not still appear to.  They look like they trigger infinite loops as google just flip-flops what you've done.

Comment: This method won't work as Google uses a different set of images, with watermark put directly on the map tile, for example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i11!2i1196!3i595!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i498211946!2m3!1e2!6m1!3e5!3m17!2sen-GB!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!2zcC5zOi02MHxwLmw6LTYw!4e0!5m1!5f2&key=AIzaSyBxXp52WUwr4ED6G9k6q8B4yRS3A7CuqJo&token=41780

Answer (score 1):

For me, Error has been fixed when activated Billing in google console. (I got 1-year developer trial)

Comment: Same for me. I did not get any warning email. I had already provided the credit card details, but for some reason Google demanded that I "upgraded" my account now after one year. After I clicked the upgrade button, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when it displays the "For development purposes only", one cannot see the map configurations as well while developing(or rather playing around with the configurations).
In my case I have not enabled billing to be associated with the API I am using and I am thinking that's the reason why its behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be related to the question, but i had the same issue on Vue. Even though i passed the API_KEY, i still had the same error. I tried @Mike Dubs suggestion, and it showed that i didn't pass API KEY(even though i did).
I used [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) library, and on documentation on how to setup google library with API KEY, they said that on main.js i should do an import like this:

> import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';

But on my case that didn't work, but this did work:

> import * as VueGoogleMaps from
> './../node_modules/vue2-google-maps/src/main';

Why, how, i don't know, but i think that vue somehow didn't understand the import.

Answer (score -8):

You can't use iframe tag in HTML, here's what you can do:
* just go into google maps point out your location
* click on "Share"
* go to "Embed a map"
* copy the HTML code
* paste it in your HTML page
* adjust height and width according to your requirement
* run it

This might work