# gmplot API issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps

i'm attempting to plot some items on a map using gmplot, my issue is that since the new google API changes it won't accept my API key? When I load the output I have the "for development purposes only" issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import gmplot
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter

gmap.apikey = "inserting my API key here"

latitude_list = [ 30.3358376, 30.307977, 30.3216419 ]

longitude_list = [ 77.8701919, 78.048457, 78.0413095 ]

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(30.3184945,
                            78.03219179999999, 13)

gmap.scatter( latitude_list, longitude_list, '# FF0000',
                            size = 40, marker = False)

gmap.polygon(latitude_list, longitude_list,
               color = 'cornflowerblue')

gmap.draw("path to save .html")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps shows "For development purposes only"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977913/google-maps-shows-for-development-purposes-only)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me.

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(30.3184945, 78.03219179999999, 13, apikey="")