# Maps JavaScript API error message "for development purpose only"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

When I try to use Maps JavaScript API I get this error:
"for development purpose only"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bkbs.png)

You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at

https://console.cloud.google.cjs?key=ZIzaSyBYpzfnPmdcSXHlV2Py8glHs4SQhoRE9qg&callback=createMap:55 om/project/_/billing/enable

Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJbJk.png)

What can i do ?

Comment: Enable billing.

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Maps shows "For development purposes only"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977913/google-maps-shows-for-development-purposes-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is not providing free API access anymore.

You have not enabled billing on your project which is causing this error. You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project.

On following link Search for : BillingNotEnabledMapError

**Error Briefing** : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

You need to follow these steps for your Google API project :

**Get Started with Google Maps Platform** : https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

Comment: thank you mate for your reply,
is there any alternative solution to work with google maps ?

Comment: Yes, You can simply search for place into Google Map and then go to Share option and then select Embade Map. That will provide you IFRAME which you can use into your pages.